# Dropdown in PHP

Tags: css, cross-browser, drop-down-menu

I am using PHP 5.2 on SUN OS server. Having problems with the following piece of code that for a drop down:

```
echo '<form action="" method="get">';
echo '<p>Information:<br />';
echo '<select name="acctno" style="width: 100px;">';
foreach ($this->account_names as $acctno => $acctname) {
   echo '<option value="'.$acctno.'">'.$acctname.'</option>';
   }
echo '</select> <input type="submit" value="view" />';
echo '</form>';
```

Worked perfectly fine on Firefox and Chrome; however there is a problem with Internet Explorer.

In IE the dropdown width is limited to the size i.e 100px. So only the first 15-16 characters of the account name are displayed all the time. However in chrome or firefox, even if only 15-16 characters are displayed initially, when the drop down arrow is clicked upon, it show the entire name (however long it may be). This does not happen with IE. So if the account name is, lets say, "1223456789abcdefghijkl" then:
For IE: shows only "123456789" all the time
Ffor chrome or firefox: shows "123456789" and when it is dropped down it show the full name as "123456789abcdefghijkl". Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
VP

Comment: Please format your question better.

Comment: Try to format your code properly. Dont just post a bunch of code in plain text. 

Your question seems to be specific to IE where as you seem to think of it as PHP specific.

Comment: I formatted the question and re-tagged. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie

Comment: thanks mercator...the link you  gave really helped!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an IE browser issue. It can't be fixed with css, but you can use javascript to fix it.

http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a PHP problem, it's a CSS problem.

Because I'm assuming it's rendering the code right, and this is only broken in one browser, it's a *browser specific bug* which you have to diagnose. If you post a link to the site or the CSS / HTML output that would help us help you.

Comment: Thanks Josh. However I cannot paste the link here since its an enterprise website. But i can probably send u images so that you could have a better idea. Let me work on that right away.

Comment: Just paste the html output from the script. And as mentioned before this is not a php based problem but a css/html IE specific problem.

Comment: BTW I am using IE 8 (if that makes a difference compared to previous versions of IE)

Comment: I get it that it is not a php problem. You want me to paste the drop down specific html output from the page source  for both IE and firefox correct??

Comment: @Ricebowl: Here is the html from the results page displayed.

<form action="" method="get"><p>Detailed Committee Information:<br /><select name="acctno" style="width: 100px;">

<option value="A6468">Some Text here I have changed 1</option><option value="A376">Some Text here I have changed 2</option>
<option value="A6448">Some Text here I have changed 3</option><option value="A4042">Some Text here I have changed 4</option>

</select> <input type="submit" value="view" /></form>

I am sorry for the late reply. I hope this helps you in helping me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with PHP, and only a bit with CSS and HTML. The main cause is that the standard (intentionally) does not specify exactly how drop-down controls should work. If you look at the standard, it doesn't even mandate the use of a [dropdown box at all](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-size-SELECT). Even the draft HTML 5 standard does not specify how the mandated functionality is to be implemented. The standard allows the control to show all options on a full-screen 3d cube if the browser implementer wants to, as long as it allows an option to be selected.

If you want precise control over what your dropdown looks like, you have to create one in javascript and fake the functionality.

Comment: Yeah..I will have to write a workarounf using Java..thats what I figured out in the meantime too..thanks anyways..

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with PHP .. the length of the dropdown box is handled most probably with the CSS and both browsers have their own way of limiting the size.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug/feature](http://www.icant.co.uk/forreview/tamingselect/) in IE (and there is a [duplicate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682764/select-dropdown-with-fixed-width-cutting-off-content-in-ie)).

In IE if you set the width, IE takes that as the exact width for the select list and all options regardless of length.

All non-IE browsers realize that when the select list opens, if some of the `option`s are larger than the specified `select` width, to widen the `(unstylable)` drop list to suit since CSS has no control over it.

Since the non-IE browsers have a usable select list I take "their" version to be correct.  IE's follows the requested width, but isn't flexible when the content doesn't fit.

In IE7 or above, you can set a `title="..."` attribute on the options so that a tooltip is provided for truncated options (note in IE6 this doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks. I will try the setting the title attribute for every option. At least that might look better than what it is right now. So basically if you are using IE nothing can be done here since all IE versions are inflexible?

Comment: There's a bunch of hacks. You can set the title attribute for IE7 & IE8, or build something that "looks" like a select list, but works better, or you can try to set the width to "auto" when the user activates that control (this will stretch the entire select list)... none of it is "perfect".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm being a tad lazy -and *optimistic*- but having tested this in both Firefox and Chrome, albeit only on Ubuntu 9.10, the *theory* -at least- is sound:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">

    select  {
        width: 5em; /* initial width, adjust to taste */
        }

    select:focus,
    select:active
        {
        width: 12em; /* the width of the select box in its focussed/active state */
        }

</style>
```

To be honest I suspect it won't work on IE -otherwise it'd be easy- so I'm thinking that either using the `title` as suggested elsewhere, or perhaps jQuery/js to adjust the width of the `select` to its widest/longest child `option` element on focus, might be the best bet.

Edited to add link to a live demo of the above: http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/select.html

And, good lord, it works on IE too. Though perhaps only on IE8 with a xhtml 1.0 strict doctype on XP SP3.