# IE does not show full content of Combo Box

Tags: html

I have the used following html code in select.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="cbotest" style="width:100px;">
   <option id="Option1">test value for option value 1</option>
   <option id="Option2">test value for option value2 long description</option>
   <option id="Option3">test value foroption value3 very long description</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But Internet Explorer displays the content of the Combo Box as given below. It truncates the content of the combo box to match the width of the combo box. The issue is present only in IE. The issue is not present in Mozilla and Firefox. How can I resolve the issue?

```
test value for
test value for
test value for
```

Comment: @mu is too short: Updated my post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select dropdown with fixed width cutting off content in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682764/select-dropdown-with-fixed-width-cutting-off-content-in-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problemen once. I resolved it by setting the width to auto when someone clicked it and resetting the width when the user closes the pop-up. I did this trick only when it was on ie.

Comment: jQuery has a nice plug in to do this, doing a search of the jQuery plugins will likely find it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the width of the combobox to make it long enough for each of the options?

Comment: Wang. We cannot increase the length as the content of the combo is generated dynamically and it will vary

Answer (score 0):

Remove a style in combo box - style="width:100px;"