# IE 8 issue of select tag width: option text gets truncated

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropdownlist width in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

I have set select tag width to fix value, according to my UI layout, but my options are too long (too wide), so they get truncated in IE8. Other browsers are showing proper output. please suggest way to fix IE8 issue

Comment: Could you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or a sample of the markup and css which you're having trouble with?

Comment: how about checking this out:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682764/select-dropdown-with-fixed-width-cutting-off-content-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

I think one solution is to define the value of 'title' property for all options