# Increase size of DropDownList in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I Have a `DropDownList` which is being populated from database on my asp.net webform. 
The items of the `DropDownList` expand according to the length of the items in Chrome and Mozilla. BUT in IE the items of the DropDownList get cut off.

I tried ...

```
var el;

$("select")
  .each(function() {
    el = $(this);
    el.data("origWidth", el.outerWidth()) // IE 8 can haz padding
  })
  .mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css("width", "auto");
  })
  .bind("blur change", function(){
    el = $(this);
    el.css("width", el.data("origWidth"));
  });
```

Which  I found http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/

but it doesnt seem to be working. Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select dropdown with fixed width cutting off content in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682764/select-dropdown-with-fixed-width-cutting-off-content-in-ie)

Comment: this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie?lq=1

Comment: I have already tried all those.. none of them seems to be working. :(

Comment: I tried http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2008/05/Viewing-Option-Text-in-IE7-thats-Wider-than-the-Select-List.cfm
And it seems to be working fine .. can anyone tell me is there any problem with this approach?