# Select Item Text getting Wrapped in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, jsf

I am getting a large text in selectItem so i gave the legnth as fixed size for selectOneMenu, So when i see the selectItems it will be full text in Chrome browser, But it is getting wrapped in IE, Please help on this

[image: Chrome]

[image]

My Code sample is

```
<m:td >

    <h:outputLabel id="PGMADMOLL960" 
                   for="newapcstatusPrc"                                    
                   value="#{msg['label.proc.apcStatus']}" />
    <m:br></m:br>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="newapcstatusPrc" 
                     style="width:150px"                            
                     value="#{ProcedureCodePricingDataBean.procedureCodePricingVO.apcStatusCode}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" 
                      itemLabel="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{ProcedureCodePricingDataBean.apcStatusCodeList}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <m:br />
    <h:message id="PGMADMM659" 
               for="newapcstatusPrc" 
               styleClass="colorRed" />
    <m:br />
</m:td>
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Should the dropdown expand to the full length?

Comment: @mish : yes it should be expanded to full length, as in the first image

Answer (score 0):

There a question with the same topic, already answered here:

[Select dropdown with fixed width cutting off content in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682764/select-dropdown-with-fixed-width-cutting-off-content-in-ie)

I would suggest this fix: http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/