# My jQuery code is not working in webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9hr3eh1t/1/) is working on firefox. But, in webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) it is not working. Any ideas?

I really can't figure it out. The nth-child css is working as well. Here is the code here

```
jQuery("#featured_1 .product-options .product-option:nth-child(2) .product-option-value option:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
    jQuery("body").css("background-color", "red");
});

jQuery("#featured_1 .product-options .product-option:nth-child(2) .product-option-value option:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
    jQuery("body").css("background-color", "green");
});
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What about it doesn't work? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: What is not working about it?

Comment: 1) That's a rediculously specific selector 2) Given the HTML, the indexes in the `eq()` funcs are incorrect. 3) Use the `val()` of the select and the `change` function to do what you require

Comment: option elements can't be reliably styled cross-browser, that's why everyone replaces them with regular elements when doing fancy dropdowns

Comment: @adeneo he's giving them a click event, not styling, though i think your comment still stands for the click events too.

Comment: Use a `change` event on the dropdown and evaluate the value, instead on relying on the click events of each option value.

Comment: @KevinB - Yes, option elements don't have reliable mouse events either.

Comment: Seems to work for me on Chromium 39. Also Chrome/Chromium no longer uses Webkit but Blink (a for of Webkit but I'd say treating Chrome and Safari as the same is no longer applicable). The JS you posted also does not make sense. `.product-option:nth-child(2)` matches nothing as there's only one `.product-option`

Comment: I mean styling is working. But click event is not working @KevinB

Comment: @RaselAhmed My guess would be said browsers don't support click events on option elements.

Comment: I am sorry for bad English. Thanks for your comment. I will try better form next time. @KevinB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419038/jquery-event-delegation-for-select-options-in-chrome and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080213/jquery-click-event-not-working-on-option-element and ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectors you have in your example are needlessly specific. Also, given the HTML the indexes you are providing the `:eq` selector are incorrect. You should use the `change` event when dealing with `select` elements so that your code works for people who use the keyboard to navigate.

That being said, you can simplify your code by using `change`, and checking the index of the selected option instead:

```
$("#featured_1 .product-option-value").change(function(){
    if (this.selectedIndex == 0) {
        // first option:
        $("body").css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
        // second option
        $("body").css("background-color", "green");
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hr3eh1t/2/)

You could even shorten this further using a ternary expression, if required:

```
$("#featured_1 .product-option-value").change(function(){
    $("body").css("background-color", this.selectedIndex == 0 ? "red" : 'green');
});
```