# jQuery click not working with select option in ie7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1. The following code appends an additional option to my select menus that appends a .click event. This code works perfectly fine in firefox/ie9, but gives me the following error in ie7/8 when clicking on the Add New Option. I've tried the select event without any luck as well. Does anybody know how to make this work in legacy browsers like ie7/8

```
$("select").append($('<option></option>').text("Add New Option").click(function(){
    alert("test");
}));
```

JS Error
SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # 
jquery-1.7.1.js, line 4179 character 2

JS Fiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/gchristman/gucgG/3/

Comment: Why do you need an `onclick` handler for `option`. Instead have a `onchange` handler on the select or incase if you need to handle on click, use `click` handler on select.

Comment: I need to handle the click event only when Add New Option has been selected. As stated below, onChange doesn't work in this case. I just tested the code with onClick in  jsfiddle and it appears to work fine. I'm not sure why it doesn't work in my app yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't attach click events to options, just subscribe to the change event on the select and check if it's the item you added? I've gave your new item a value of 0 in order to identify it in the change.

```
$("select").append($('<option></option').text("Add New Option").val(0));

$("select").change(function () {
    if $("select option:selected").val() == 0) {
        alert("test");
    } 
});
```

Comment: Just tried this code, it does work in legacy ie browsers, except it's alerting on all changes. I can easily repair that though.

Comment: Cool, just query what's in the .val(), it might be a string so either parseInt on it or check == "0" :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the onchange event.
Try this instead:

```
$("select").append($('<option></option>').text("Add New Option")).change(function(){
    alert("test");
}));
```

Related: [Click event on select option element in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/jquery-click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome)

Comment: You're attaching the change event to the new option and not the select?

Comment: @George did you try using my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.on("click", function() {
    alert("test");
}));
```

instead of:

```
.click(function() {
    alert("test");
}));
```

See if that works?

Comment: Live was deprecated for on in 1.7 :)

Comment: as @mattytommo said, Live is replaced in jQuery 1.7.1, use "on" http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Iro :) I had that problem too.

Answer (score 0):

for ie7/8 use javascript: [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Intacto/gucgG/8/)

```
<select id="sel" onchange="test(this.value)"><option>option1</option></select>

<script language="javascript"><!--
//<![CDATA[
s=document.getElementById("sel");
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = "add";
opt.innerHTML = "Add New Option";
s.appendChild(opt);

function test(val){
    if (val = "add"){
        alert("test");
    }
}

//]]>
--></script>
```