# Jquery show div on click of option from a select field don't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery

I did try a very simple test to display a row when i click on an option of a select field. It does work on every browser i believe, except Chrome. It does nothing at all and when i check the javascript debug console it doesn't even give an error.

```html
<select name="test">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2" id="show_div">two</option>
</select>

<div id="show_block" style="display:none;">it works!</div>
```

The very simple jquery

```js
$('#show_div').click(function(){
    $('#show_block').show();
});
```

i tried instead of click, change, but no result in Chrome. Idea's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('select[name="test"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).find('#show_div').is(':selected'))
        $('#show_block').show();
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ddCA6/)

Comment: should it be `$('select').change(function(){
    if ($(this).find('#show_div').is(':selected'))
          $('#show_block').show();
  });`

Comment: +1 for morphing this into the correct answer like a ninja. wow. and a live demo!

Comment: I did mistype the class, it should have been # but i knew where to go from answer one ( edited version ) Thanks for the very fast answer! it works perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be binding a click event to an item in a select list, you should bind to the click of the whole select, and then check which item is selected, like this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 2)
    {
          $('.show_block').show();
     }
  });
```

This question is similar: [Click event on select option element in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/jquery-click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome)

Comment: Note that you "hardcode" the value of the option inside your code.

Comment: Well yes, but you could argue that using the ID is hardcoding the option within the code. Depends how they want to identify the object...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an id attribute on your select element, but you reference it by id in your Jquery code. This works in chrome and here it is in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WcM3z/).

HTML

```
<select id="show_div" name="test">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2" id="show_div">two</option>
</select>
<div id="show_block" style="display:none;">it works!</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#show_div').change(function(){
  $('#show_block').show();
});​
```

Comment: I do not see that in his post, simply that his test did not work. You read minds, do ya?

Comment: I'm not attacking you personaly. take a look on this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ddCA6/1/).