# Angular ng-repeat that works fine in FF somehow comments out in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, angularjs

I've got this code in the jsp (sized down a bit):

```
<div class="popup default" ng-app="interview" ng-init="employeeId = '${employee.id}'; findTimelineEntries(); getAddInterviewRights(); getEditInterviewRights();" ng-controller="TimelineCtrl">
  <div class="box-wrapper edit" ng-show="hasAddInterviewRights">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="pointer"></div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div class="icon close" ></div>
        <div class="form-item">
        <!-- cut -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form" id="convo">
        <div class="form-item">
          <!-- cut -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-break"></div>
        <div class="form-item">
          <div class="label">
            <div class="fi-content">
              Currently open goals
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="value">
            <div class="editable" ng-repeat="goal in interviewForm.goals" ng-click="openEditable($event.target)">
              <div class="icon edit"></div>
              <div class="icon close" ng-click="closeEditable($event.target)"></div>
                {{goal.shortDescription}}
              <div class="ed-content">
              <div class="form-item">
                <div class="label">
                <div class="fi-content">
                  Deadline
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="value">
                <input type="text" ng-model="goal.dueDate" ui-date="dateOptions" size="15" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
              <div class="label">
                <div class="fi-content">
                  Status
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="value select">
              <select ng-model="goal.status" ng-options="code as description for (code, description) in goalStatusses"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-item">
            <div class="label">
              <div class="fi-content">
                Comment
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="value">
              <div class="fi-content">
                <table class="plain">
                  <tr ng-repeat="progress in goal.progresses">
                    <td>{{progress.progressDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{progress.progressReport}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="editable">
        <div class="icon add"></div>
          <div class="icon close" ng-click="closeEditable($event.target)"></div>
          Add a new goal
```

And it works in Firefox (20.0.1) just like it should: It shows 2 current goals and the option to add a new goal. But somehow the same jsp doesn't work that well in Chrome (27) as it just shows the option to add a new goal

When looking into the HTML with the Developer Tools I see that the ng-repeat is commented out by Chrome, but why would it do that??

I googled on ng-repeat getting commented out, but the answer there was that the div using the ng-repeat was not inside the div with the ng-controller, but that's certainly not the case with my code

The HTML taken from the Developer Tools:

```
<div class="value">
  <!-- ngRepeat: goal in interviewForm.goals -->
  <div class="editable">
    <div class=icon add"></div>
    <div class=icon close" ng-click="closeEditable($event.target)" style="dispay:none;"></div>
      Add new goal
```

I've checked other browsers and it doesn't work in Safari (5.1) either and also doesn't work in IE8 although a colleague says it does work in his IE9

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your issue?

Comment: Dunno, jsfiddle consist of css, js and html, so how would I get the objects like interviewForm in there?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question about getting objects in... here's a template one I use a lot that you can roll with: http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/10/ Feel free to delete the stuff you don't need.

Comment: I cannot get the goals array working, maybe you've got an idea as it seems you're more familiar with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/112/

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have the time to fix or make your fiddle. A quick check shows that there is a error in your code (when I look in the console) so go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally found what was going wrong and it actually was a

```
    $('.select .option').click(function() {
    var choice = $(this).text();
        etc.
```

that had to be changed into

```
$(".select #itemAddSelector").change(function(){
    var selectedOption = $(this).children(":selected");
    var choice = $(selectedOption).text();
        etc.
```

As the function that retrieves the goals from the controller was never called in Chrome, because Chrome doesn't process a jQuery click event on an option ([Click event on select option element in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/jquery-click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome)).
So it just commented in the HTML about ng-repeat saying it had tried to iterate over the goal objects, but there were no objects present ... pfff, I've been looking in the wrong direction for too long.