# Javascript: Append Children With Functions: FireFox vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have a test page based on a problem I've been experiencing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #selectDiv { display: inline; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeOption(args) {
                var sel = document.createElement("select");
                var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
                var opt2 = document.createElement("option");
                var opt3 = document.createElement("option");
                opt1.value = "opt1";
                opt1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Option 1"));
                sel.appendChild(opt1);
                opt2.value = "opt2";
                opt2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Option 2"));
                sel.appendChild(opt2);
                opt3.value = "opt3";
                opt3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Option 3"));
                sel.appendChild(opt3);

                // working on FireFox, not on Chrome
                opt1.onclick = function() {changeOption()}
                opt2.onclick = function() {changeOption()}
                opt3.onclick = function() {changeOption()}

                document.getElementById("selectDiv").appendChild(sel);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a test.</h1>
        <div id="selectDiv">
        <select id="test_select1" onchange="changeOption()">
            <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In FireFox, this works as I would expect: each new select is created with three options; selecting one creates a new select with three options.

But in Chrome, it stops on the second select. That is, the newly created select doesn't seem to get the onclick function. The first select happily creates more selects, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

Safari behaves like Chrome but that's to be expected, right? I've tried a jQuery version, but it doesn't work either. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: This likely has something to do with how the browsers handle pointing to event handlers. You can fix this by using a delegate listening to the selectDiv. I'm not sure if you are using jQuery or not so the implementation will vary.

Comment: "it stops on the second select", the first select works because you built in html.

Comment: See also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a change handler to the select element, not a click handler on the options. So this:

```
sel.onchange = function(){
   changeOption();
}
```

Instead of:

```
opt1.onclick = function() {changeOption()}
opt2.onclick = function() {changeOption()}
opt3.onclick = function() {changeOption()}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c1kmtnfd/

Comment: You haven't explained why. Why don't the onclick events work in Chrome?

Comment: For starters, it's bad practice. A click event wouldn't be triggered if I tabbed and changed the option with my keyboard—a change event on the select would. I'm looking for a specification of Chrome implementation of onclick.

Comment: I haven't found any official documentation from Chrome; however, attaching an onchange handler to the select is definitely more reliable cross browser. Here's a table of implemented events on the option element across different browsers: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html

Comment: Yes it does. Go to the fiddle I posted in Firefox and Chrome and see for yourself.

Comment: Sorry, where is that?

Comment: Hey it does work! But mine doesn't....Oh, you added the onchange() to the select, not the option...my mistake!

Comment: Are you trying the solution in the code you posted, or in another code base?