# Angular 2 (click) does not work in Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am using in my html template something like this:

```
 <div class="input-group" id="geo-type">
        <div class="input-label" [style.color]="geographicLocationColor">{{geoLocationTitle}}</div>
        <select class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-select" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <option value="" selected hidden>{{geographicLocationPl}}</option>
            <option *ngFor="#geo of geographicLocations" (click)="locationOnSelect(geo)">{{geo.description}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

If I select something in dropdown menu with firefox, the method *locationOnSelect* is called (I am doing some other GET identified by location), but in Chrome nothing will happen - the method *locationOnSelect* is not called.

Also I have problem with IE (ver 11), locationOnSelect is okay, but on  the next GET (user select something in second dropdown menu) the IE crashes - stop working. So my app is 100% working in firefox only. Any ideas?

Comment: I see no `(click)` directive on select attribute. Add that and check.

Comment: I moved my (click)="locationOnSelect(geo)" to select tag and now, the app crashes because geo is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `(click)="..."` or `(change)="..."` on the `<select>` instead of the `<option>`

See also [Click event on select option element in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome)

```
<div class="input-group" id="geo-type">
    <div class="input-label" [style.color]="geographicLocationColor">{{geoLocationTitle}}</div>
    <select [ngModel]="selectedGeo" (ngModelChange)="locationOnSelect($event)"
       class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-select" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <option selected hidden>{{geographicLocationPl}}</option>
        <option *ngFor="#geo of geographicLocations" [ngValue]="geo">{{geo.description}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I moved my (click)="locationOnSelect(geo)" to select tag and now, the app crashes because geo is undefined.

Comment: You can use `[ngModel]` with `(ngModelChange)` to get the requested behavior.

Comment: I tried it, but I must doing something wrong, still geo is undefined. Could you send me an example of html? Thank you.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the issue in https://plnkr.co/edit/wnLWAW?p then I'll check again.

Comment: If it will be neccessary I will add my code to plunker, but it is very extensive (html, ts, services etc.). When I copy/paste your html example, I am getting an error: No value accessor for '' in [selectedGeo in TicketComponent@1:43]

Comment: Sorry, I added the `ngModel` stuff to the wrong tag. It should be on the `<select>`

Comment: Now app started and does not crash, but if I select someting, locationOnSelect still not called. I have some console.log() in this method and this log still it is not displayed...

Comment: Please create a Plunker. It shouldn't be necessary to add lot of code in addition to that in my answer. Only some sample data and the `locationOnSelect(event) {}` method that allows to verify that the code behaves as expected. I won't look through lots of your code.

Comment: But in Chrome something happens - so locationOnSelect is called, I am testing it, but now, it does not work in Firefox (when I was writing post above, I tried it in Firefox).

Comment: You might use an outdated Angular2 version. This was fixed recently for Firefox and Edge.

Comment: Now I am using "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15".

Comment: I changed it into beta 17 and now it works in Chrome and Firefox, thank you very much, you are my savior! I also read, that the latest version of Angular2 is 2.0.0-rc.1, but npm does not know it, the latest npm is "2.0.0-beta.17".

Comment: The rc-versions contain the new router with lots of changes. Don't be overhasty. Docs need to be updated. Lots of issues. If you're brave you can switch of course ;-) I would wait at least a few days. They are working hard to get the issues fixed.

Comment: I changed all my app to your html template and it works in Chrome and Firefox. IE now does not crash, but there is missing a lot of logic - I will solve it later. I have only one small question, now my placeholders are missing, do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "my placeholders are missing"?

Comment: Before making changes, my app has dropdown menu and there was a placeholder, ie "Please select location...", this placeholder is created by this <option value="" selected hidden>{{geographicLocationPl}}</option>. Before I have this - https://ctrlv.cz/jBYq now I have this - http://postimg.org/image/hfz0g47mp/

Comment: You could try to create a property in you component like `this.placeholderValue = {}; this.selectedGeo = this.placeholderValue; (for example in the constructor and then change the placeholder to `<option value="" selected hidden [ngValue]="placeholderValue">{{geographicLocationPl}}</option>`

Comment: I did exactly what you described, but it does not work , it's empty, so I have still this http://postimg.org/image/hfz0g47mp/.

Comment: I can't open the image. You could add it to your question instead. SO allows to add images.

Comment: I solved it by deleting this value="". Thank you again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111010/discussion-between-loutocky-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: But it works on firefox using on option tag