# Bind event on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following HTML

```
<select>
  <option value="">filter</option>
  <option data-behavior="toggle-visibility" data-scope="a" value="a">a</option>
  <option data-behavior="toggle-visibility" data-scope="b" value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

and I need to fire up a Javascript callback when any of the options is selected.

I have the following piece of Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $(document).on("EVENT", "[data-behavior~=toggle-visibility]", function() {
   ...
  });
});
```

Is there an event I can use to achieve my goal?

PS - I understand I could move `data-behavior="toggle-visibility"` to the `select` tag and then listen for `change` and get the currently selected value. However, since that piece of Javascript is already used with other elements, I need to keep the `data-behavior` attribute on the `option`s.

It should work here https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/535895/

Comment: _“I need to keep the data-behavior attribute on the options”_ - well then leave it there, and in your change handler on the select element first of all check whether the currently selected option is one with that attribute - if so, proceed with whatever needs doing, otherwise don’t ...

Comment: The goal here is not just to make it work. I understand how to make it work. I am trying to adapt the same piece of code I already have to a new requirement. And, in the code I already have I get additional attributes from the element with `data-behavior~=toggle-visibility`.

Comment: Pretty sure that won’t work, browsers don’t fire some events on option elements, see f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/

Comment: @CBroe think so too, but before replacing the select with something else I'd like to make it sure. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your higher level objective is but if it is to hide/show options that is not supported cross browser either the same way events aren't supported

Comment: No, my goal is to make a `GET` request.

Comment: So why don't you set `value`?

Comment: As mentioned multiple times, this piece of code is used by other DOM elements, which don't have `value`.

Comment: @Sig that is irrelevant regarding <option>` since they don't support events

Answer (score 3):

You should be using on change event instead:

The example is as follows:

```js
$("select").on("change", function(e) {
  var sel = $(this).find(":selected");
  var attr = sel.attr("data-behavior");
  console.log(attr + "....." + $(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">filter</option>
  <option data-behavior="toggle-visibility" data-scope="a" value="a">a</option>
  <option data-behavior="toggle-visibility" data-scope="b" value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the PS, I need to add the listener to the `option` and not to the `select`.

Comment: I believe that is not possible, but you can create your own custom drop down using li ul or divs

Comment: But you can use onmouseup event for this. I have updated have a look.

Comment: You are still putting it on the select. I have tried on my code and it does not work.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle with scenario used by you?

Comment: text says use change event but code shows `mouseup` which makes no sense on `<select>`

Comment: @charlietfl that was the alternative suggestion suggested to the user in accordance to the comments received

Comment: Using `mouseup` makes no sense. Will fire more than once. Once when you open the `<select>` and once when you make selection

Answer (score 0):

**Html Code:**

```
<select id="maker-list">
  <option value="">filter</option>
  <option data-behavior="toggle-visibility" data-scope="a" value="a">a</option>
  <option data-behavior="toggle-visibility" data-scope="b" value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
$('#maker-list').off('change').on('change', e => {
  
  selectedValue = $('#maker-list').val();
  // Here you can call another function with selectedValue
});
```

> In above JavaScript Code, we bind change even and unbind the same event after selecting value so that it will not fire twice. [jquery help](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will work ... happy coding :)

```js
$("select").on("change", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">filter</option>
  <option data-behavior="toggle-visibility" data-scope="a" value="a">a</option>
  <option data-behavior="toggle-visibility" data-scope="b" value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the PS, I need to add the listener to the `option` and not to the `select`.

Comment: so what ever the option you are selected you need to add a listener