# Bind a function call to a <option> element in svelte

Tags: svelte

Hi I have a select element where the last option is supposed to initiate a rest call to log out the user

Here is what i have tried so far

```
<select ref:logout>
    <option selected value={$user.role}>{$user.role}</option>
    {#each $user.pages as page}
        <option value={page}>{page}</option>
    {/each}
    <option on:click="logout()" value='logout'>Logout</option>
</select>

<script>
    export default {
      methods: {
        logout() {
          console.log("well hello");
      }
    };
</script>
```

The problem is that the logout method never gets called

**Update**
The problem was that I was using `click` event instead of `change` and placed it on the `option` element instead of the `select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you change it to be a onchange event on the select element? Then add an if statement to detect value=='logout'.
Similar issue but without svelte:
[Click event on select option element in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome)

Comment: I should have mentioned that i was looking for svelte events rather than dom events, as i currently don't include jQuery in this project. Guss ill just have to create a fake drop-down using buttons, since the select element was never intended for this purpose.

Comment: What about <select on:change="doStuff(this.value)"> . . .</select>
 

Then have a method
    doStuff(v){
      if(v=='logout'){console.log('do it');}
    }