# How to fire an dropdownlist event instantaneously?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**UPDATE2** : The 'jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js' file was an issue for some reason actually...is that file only for intellisense ? ...i commented the include out for that and it works fine now..

**UPDATE**: OK so it worked when I used the original js file- 
   `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js`

I have a dropdown: `<%= Html.DropDownList("dropdownid", new SelectList(Model.WeightToLoseList, "Value", "Text")) %>`

in my jQuery, I assign change event like this:

```
$('#dropdownid').change(function() {......});
```

But this event only is firing when i select anything and then click anywhere outside on the page..but I want it to work instantly and show me once I select items from the dropdownlist and not after i click outside...this behaviour is reproduced only on chrome and firefox. But it works fine on **IE8**. Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* `change()` will not fire until the user has committed to their selection by releasing the mouse.

Comment: yea..that is how i want it to work but currently it only works if after releasing mouse i click anywhere else..But it works fine in IE 8..has anyone been able to reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [Fire event each time a DropDownList item is selected with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898463/fire-event-each-time-a-dropdownlist-item-is-selected-with-jquery/898620#898620)

Vincent Ramdhanie's answer was:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var clicknum = 0;
 $("#dropdownid").click(function(){
        clicknum++;
        if(clicknum == 2){
            alert($(this).val());
                clicknum = 0;
        }
 });
});
```

Comment: This does not work..as i want it to fire when I select an item from dropdownlist..but it fires with this only when i click on the dropdownlist again..