# How to detect when user clicks on an element already selected from a select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select and a function bound to on change (ng-change), the thing is I want this function to work when the user clicks the already selected element, so they can easily reuse the already selected action.

This is my html (with [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/))

```
select ng-model="selectedAction" ng-options="action.label for action in Actions" ng-change="chooseAction()"
    option ng-selected="users.items.length == 0" value="" Select an Action
```

Is this possible or I'll have to add a button to make it work?

Already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964362/select-already-selected-item-in-dropdown-select-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354367/html-select-element-onchange-trigger-for-already-selected-option), looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't detect if they clicked the same option again, so what I did was that everytime they chose an option, I would do this:

```
$scope.selectedAction = {
    label: 'Select an Action',
    id: 0
}
```

So it goes back to the default action.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't just assign the same method to the `ng-click` attribute as well?

```
<select ng-model="selectedAction" ng-options="action.label for action in Actions" ng-change="chooseAction()" ng-click="chooseAction()">
```

Comment: That just repeats the action on the select and doesn't work when clicking the already selected option, so that's the reason why I don't do that. I found a solution, but I'll wait to see if there's anything else before posting it.

Comment: If you have a solution please post it, it could be the best solution. If not it can be commented on and evolved.

Comment: Added the "solution" I found. I think the only way to have something like this would be if you made your own select implementation or hacking something on top of `Select2.js` or some other `Select` library.