# Jquery append when option from dropdown list clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

Why doesn't this work?

```
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#custom_field option').click(function(){
        $('#custom_field_input').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');      
        $('#custom_field_input td:last').append($(this).find(":selected").text());
     });
     });
     </script>
```

I found out that there is a .change function for this and it works but does not relate to me as i need to have the text appended **even if there is no change in the value of the select dropdown.**

Meaning.

**User clicks on option1, appends option1 text.**

**User clicks on option 1 again, another option 1 text gets appended.**

Comment: You need "User clicks on option1, appends option1 text.

User clicks on option 1 again, another option 1 text gets appended."??

Comment: something simmilar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898463/fire-event-each-time-a-dropdownlist-item-is-selected-with-jquery

Comment: Just dun understand why **.change** is okay but **.click** isn't

Answer (score 0):

Make the custon_field_input element on click of custom_field_opotion as empty with following code :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#custom_field option').click(function(){
  $('#custom_field_input').html('');      
    $('#custom_field_input').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');      
    $('#custom_field_input td:last').append($(this).find(":selected").text());
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#custom_field').change(function(){
    $('#custom_field_input').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');      
    $('#custom_field_input td:last').append($(this).val());
 });
 });
 </script>
```

this should work in your case as well

Comment: no. The .change method doesn't work as i need it on every click

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#custom_field option').click(function(){
     $('#custom_field_input').html('');      
     $('#custom_field_input').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');      
     $('#custom_field_input td:last').append($(this).find(":selected").text());
 });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also get help from

http://www.guy.footring.net/randomStuff/selectBox.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use blur or focusout events instead of click.

```
$('#custom_field option').focusout(function(){
....
 });   

$('#custom_field option').blur(function(){
....
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#custom_field').click(function () {
        jQuery("#custom_field_input").val(jQuery("#custom_field_input").val() + jQuery("option:selected", this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Made 2 changes. Used live incase your selects are getting populated later dynamically. If not use simple .click(). Also instead of .find(":selected"), use .find("option:selected").

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#custom_field option').live('click',function(){
    $('#custom_field_input').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');      
    $('#custom_field_input td:last').append($(this).find("option:selected").text());
 });
 });
 </script>
```