# Jquery callback when any select box option is chosen (not changed)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown select form element. When an option is selected, I want to do something. Even if the value that is chosen from the dropdown is the already-selected option. So "on change" won't work in this case.

How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried `onclick`, and manually doing the selection logic?

Comment: jsfiddle for click - http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/9y6tm93w/ ,i guess, it is firing twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452103/jquery-select-change-event-when-selecting-the-same-value

Comment: Post your code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your option is "actually" not changing, jQuery change event won't fire automatically. Instead you need to bind it. Use the click event as suggested by @epoch:-

Sample Code:-

```
             //Intialize a local variable
             var x = 0;
             $('#single').click(function () {
                 //Increment local variable by 1.
                 x = x + 1;
                 //Since click event will be fired twice (once during focus & second while   selecting the option) compare '2' for same selection
                 if (x == 2) {
                     $(this).change();
                     x = 0;
                 }
             }).change(function () {
                 console.log(1);
                 //To reset the value of x back to 0, set it as -1 here (since click event will be fired after change).
                 x = -1;
             });
```

Comment: Cheers, I think this general approach is the way to go.