# Call a function when a selected item is selected again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectbox

I have a dropdown menu in my web page. I already used `x.change(y);` to do some thing when the selected item changes. But I want to call a function when the user selecting the same selected item.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<select class="dropdown dateFilter" id="month" data-live-search="true" name="month">
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

and related js:

```
$('#month').change(function () {
  //Do some things
});
```

Comment: Hi, you have a wrong bracket in your code `<option value="2")>February</option>`. Is this your actual code or just a typo in your question?

Comment: oh, thanks for your comment. I will fix this, but its not in my running code.

Comment: You're welcome. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452103/jquery-select-change-event-when-selecting-the-same-value perhaps that's interesting for you.

Comment: There's not a real possibility and nearly all solutions will fail in at least one browser. Can you refactor your code to eliminate the need to do this?

Comment: @Nope That don't work in my problem.

Comment: @chrispbacon Not really. I tried that before asking here but unfortunately, I don't find  any solution that solve this issue and I really need a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I preferred to use onclick. Give it a try maybe it will help you

```js
document.querySelector("select.dropdown").onclick = (event)=>{
  if(event.clientX == 0 && event.clientY == 0){
    value = event.target.value;
    console.log("selected "+value)
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="dropdown dateFilter" id="month" data-live-search="true" name="month">
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a `click` event on select `option` and can cross check clicked option and selected dropdown value as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name=month] option').click(function() { 
        if ($(this).attr('value') == $("#month").val()) {
            // user clicked on selected option
        } else {
            // user clicked on another option
        }
    });
});
```

Your HTML code as:

```
<select class="dropdown dateFilter" id="month" data-live-search="true" name="month">
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Please add the comment for downvoting @unknown voter?