# jQuery append HTML code into textarea

Tags: jquery, select, append

I'm trying to 'append' HTML elements into a textarea. I figured out how to insert the HTML elements:

see here -------> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUFhA/) <--------

But I cannot figure out how to APPEND.

Here's the code anyways:

HTML

```
<select id='sel' size='1'>
  <option>&#60;&#62;&#60;&#47;&#62;</option>
  <option>&#60;p&#62;&#60;&#47;p&#62;</option>
  <option>&#60;div&#62;&#60;&#47;p&#62;</option>
  <option>&#60;a&#62;&#60;&#47;a&#62;</option>
  </select><br/><br/>
<textarea id='txtarea'></textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    $('textarea').html($(this).val());        
  });
});
```

Does anyone know how to APPEND html element text to the textarea? What I mean is if you keep clicking the "<p></p>" item it will keep inserting itself after the other.

Thanks!!

Comment: textarea has an opening and closing tag, so shouldn't .append() work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var currentVal = $('textarea').val();
        $('textarea').val(currentVal + $(this).val());    
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/raA83/)

Answer (score 5):

Create a temporary variable outside your event handler and keep appending to that, then update the textarea with the variable value, like this:

```
var tempValue = '';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/vWFQQ/1/

The issue you're going to run in to is that `change()` will not pick up the multiple selections for the same drop down, however, this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/898761/2469255 may be of use...

Hope this helps

**EDIT:** see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/vWFQQ/2/) updated fiddle for the `.selected()` extension.

Comment: +1 -- great explanation.  Didn't think about that with the `change()` event (although makes sense).  I still prefer the `.append()` method, but this is the best solution!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I don't know why but I personally dislike mixing vanilla JS and jQuery. I don't have a compelling reason for it, it just *feels* wrong to me.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) with `createtextnode`:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('#txtarea').append(document.createTextNode($(this).val()));   
})
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hgH7/)