# IE 6 dropdown selection area too narrow

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

I have a dropdown menu with the width set to 142px however the selection area when you drop down the menu needs to be larger as it has text that exceeds this width. Firefox (and most modern browsers) is clever and extends the selection area to fit in this text. However IE 6 and unchecked newer versions of IE do not show this text and keep the selection area the same width as the dropdown unclicked. The problem lies here, how can I get IE to extend the selection area where you click the selection you want without increasing the width of the dropdown area with out the dropdown selection showing. Hope that makes sense.

:D cheers (DEATH TO IE)

Comment: Can you set selection area widths?

Comment: This is a duplicate question many times over. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie

Comment: @mercator: that solution doesn't work in ie6.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't.  Even in the best of times there is very little control for dropdown boxes and IE6 is usually considered the worst of times.

Answer (score 1):

A quick'n'dirty I just managed to trial-and-error myself to (the [Yahoo hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie#74550) is bloated, but better if you want animated growth/shrinking):

```
<html>
<body>
  <select style="width:100px;" onmouseover="this.style.width='auto'; this.focus();" onblur="this.style.width='100px';">
    <option>Tiny</option>
    <option>Und das verrry, verrrry, verrrrrrrrrrry long one!</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```