# Asp .net drop down width

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down. I want the drop down to be of 200 px width but when some one clicks on the drop down button,(the contents which come below the drop down )should be of a greater width(say 300 px or self adjusting width based on text). Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour in  Firefox. I think its not possible in Internet Explorer.

EDIT: redirected from google to Stackoverflow, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)