# Select box hides the lengthy text as its option when displayed in IE whereas it is displayed perfect with Firefox

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Select box hides the lengthy text as its option when displayed in IE whereas it is displayed perfect with Firefox, How can I rectify this issue...

```
<select name="product" id="product" style="width:135px;" onChange="javascript:refill();bannersize();">
    <option value="">Select Product</option>
    <?php while($result=mysql_fetch_object($sql_query))
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $result->categories_id;?>"><?php echo $result->categories_name;?></option>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: see update question with code

Comment: Show the finished rendered HTML code please, the PHP parts are not really relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdownlist width in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question, the answer uses the YUI library: [Dropdownlist width in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

This page also has a nice solution: http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2008/05/Viewing-Option-Text-in-IE7-thats-Wider-than-the-Select-List.cfm