# dropdown width incorrect in ie

Tags: php, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropdownlist width in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

hello
can someone tell me why there is a difference in the way dropdowns are displayed in ie and ff. i have set a width in css for the select class and in firefox the box expands to accommodate the full address but ie does not. i have included 2 grabs to show you. is there a solution so ie displays full address like ff? many thanks

For some reason i cannot include images. any suggestion as how i can show them to you.

code:

```
    .webform select {
        font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        width:175px;
        }

$address_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company_com ORDER BY address1_com ASC");
$dropdown ="<select name='address'>";  
$dropdown.= "<option SELECTED value=\"\">Select an Address</option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($address_result)) {
    $address = $row["address1_com"].$row["address2_com"].$row["address3_com"];
    $dropdown .= "<option value='".$row['address']."'>$address</option>";
}
$dropdown .= "</select>";
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie - the solution includes using JS to fix the width of the dropdown box

Answer (score 0):

I believe setting the width on the option tag should yield the results you are after.

Images could be linked to by putting them on yfrog, photobucket, picassa or another such image hosting site then linked here?