# How to properly adjust CSS Form Select field if content is larger than image

Tags: css, forms

I have customized the look and field of my form's select field with the following code:

```
.formbox select { width:240px; border:0; padding:11px 15px; font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000; margin-top:5px; background: url(../images/search_bg.gif) left top no-repeat; }
```

the field works well except in the case where the content within my select field is wider than 240 pixels.

If I remove the width field, the drop down is fine but my actual select button is way over the right of the field background.

If i change the width, the image I have for my width is distorted and/or not long enough so it looks tacky.

Is it possible to have the select field itself at one width and any dropdown content at another?

## EDIT

I found this link: [Dropdownlist width in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie) but I am not looking to use JS at all.

Comment: given the space, how would you like to deal with text that overflows that width?...  You could truncate it and add '...' as one option.

Comment: I am not looking to truncate, I want the field to expand on the dropdown

Comment: Then you probably want to set a `min-width` attribute instead.  Perhaps this can be done to the background element as well.

Comment: does not work - i tried that at first pass. see 2nd to last sentence above edit - My background image is not wide enough to encompass the data returned and will either be distorted or blank. It is obvious I could simply create a new css element with a new background but trying to avoid doing that for one instance on one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this cross-browser. Some browsers allow a limited amount of customisation of select elements, but generally it's not worth the effort.

If you really need to have a custom look, then I'd recommend going with a full javascript solution.