# max-width in select tag is not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i have a select tag,...
like this,..

```
<select style="max-width:150px"> 
     <option value='1'>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ...(let's say a long words)
     ...... 
</select>
```

it's works in FF,.. but not ie,.. than i change max-width with width `style="width:150px"`
it's works in both,.. but,..
in ie... the text is truncated

anyone can help me?
am i doing wrong?
is there a better way to fix it?

sorry if my english bad :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdownlist width in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an article that may explain why max-width doesn't work in the version of IE you're using:

[max-width in Internet Explorer](http://www.svendtofte.com/code/max_width_in_ie/)

It shows an example of how to simulate max-width in IE using CSS expressions:

```
<html>
<style>
body {
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;}

p {
border:1px solid red;
max-width:800px;
width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 800? "800px": "auto" );
}
</style>
<body>
<p>
[a lot of text]
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

*Disclaimer: [I'm not a fan of CSS expressions](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#AvoidCSSExpressions), but this should work, anyway.*

Comment: Just a heads up; your max-width link no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

[This jQuery plugin](http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/ie-select-width/) fixes the problem you're describing.

> Setting the fixed width of a select element in Internet Explorer [6/7/8]
>   will cause all of the select options that are wider than the select's
>   set width to be cropped.
>
> Applying this plugin makes the select element in Internet Explorer
>   appear to work as it would work in [modern browsers].

Comment: Who's asking for jQuery here? ;)

Comment: @Sander: If it was possible to fix this without JavaScript, then *why would the above jQuery plugin exist*? The accepted answer also uses JavaScript (A CSS expression, [which is bad and *should* be replaced with JavaScript!!](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#AvoidCSSExpressions)). If you're using JavaScript *in the slightest* you might as well be using a library such as jQuery. If you've found a pure CSS solution to this problem then please share it, and your downvote is warranted. Otherwise, you're downvoting a valid solution to this problem for no reason.

Comment: @Sander: Also take a look at the question linked in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie. Surprise, surprise it's chock full of JavaScript/jQuery fixes.

Comment: Let me explain my downvote. The reason why I did that was because in this specific case no jQuery was asked. Andy West proposed a solution with JavaScript through CSS expressions. And that is where the big difference is: JavaScript is not jQuery. Please consider the fact that not every website on this planet is using that library. ;) (continued in the next comment)

Comment: (Continued from the previous comment) If a solution with plain JavaScript is alright, then no jQuery is needed. I'm getting a little tired of everyone thinking that jQuery contains/is the solution to anything, in the end jQuery is nothing more than a great, but also big, library to resolve cross browser issues with regards to JavaScript. So, why include an entire jQuery library just for this fix? That's my point. :) I will upvote your post again (when I can) because I appreciate your effort in thinking along, but I just don't think that jQuery should be the solution to just anything.