# Is there a way to expand a drop down horizontally after you click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down in a form and it needs to be restricted to 400 pixels in width, but some of the options are much longer.  Is there a way to expand the drop down after you click it that also works in IE...possibly a JS solution?

Comment: I think your problem is already solved here: [Dropdownlist width in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)  (marked as duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure try this

```
<select name="expand" id="expand" onclick="expand(this);">...</select>
```

Note that the above html is just a snippet, you need to complete it to suit you

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function expand(obj)
{
    obj.style.width = "450px"; //any value wider than OR
    //obj.style.width = "auto"; //to automatically take length of it values
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simple jQuery solution:

```
<select name="expand" id="expand" onclick="$(this).width('450px');">...</select>
```