# How to add horizontal ScrollBar in t:selectOneListbox?

Tags: java, html, jsf

I can't display the entire content of my elements in my `<t:selectOneListbox>` which renders a HTML `<select>` element. How can I add a horizontal scrollbar to a `<t:selectOneListbox>`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a MSIE-only bug. When you set a fixed width on a HTML `<select>` element, then MSIE will *also* apply this on the opened list while the normal webbrowsers like Firefox, Chrome and others will expand the list to the content width.

This is not specific to JSF and cannot be solved by JSF. There are a lot of solutions for this particular issue, the majority is JavaScript based. You can find them all in this question: [Dropdownlist width in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie).