# Drop-down width -- IE labels crop

Tags: css

I know it is possible to set a CSS width for a drop-down menu. In FF the top window is affected by it, while the option items scale as far as the content in them, however in IE the options are also as wide as the window, thus cutting the options' labels.

Is there a better way to control the width of SELECT element?

```
<select style="width:100px">
    <option>Very long label 1 is gpoing to be here</option>
    <option>Very long label 2 is gpoing to be here</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdownlist width in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When talking to developers, please refer to `select` elements as
  `select` elements, because a "drop-down" can infer something else
  entirely.
- There is a fix [here](http://css-tricks.com/1994-select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `width: auto` rule. This automatically sets the width according to the length of the options.

If that doesn't work for you, you could use Javascript to dynamically change the width of the select when it is moused over, but nothing simple will make IE8 and below act like it is supposed to.