# Dropdownlist width in IE 8/9

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

the picture below describes my current problem. Is there a (css)way to achieve the "Good Browsers" behaviour (like FF) in IE8/9 without JavaScript/JQuery?
Found some old posts from 2008 / 2011, but without any possible solution.

(e.g. [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie) [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585512/drop-down-width-ie-labels-crop) )

[image]

Thanks alot!

Comment: use larger width and/or another select for grouping

Comment: This' alternate solution for Ancient Browsers: `select:active, select:focus { width: auto; }`. You can try JS solution for better usage. This' just an idea.

Comment: same question from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript 

hope this help you.... [click me](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sNwrs/10/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
select{
width: 250px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

That code works only on IE browsers.

Comment: The problem with that solution is, that ALL boxes will have a width of 250px , and if a text is longer than 250 it will still get cut off.

Comment: How about giving the boxes IDs and giving each the width it requires?

Comment: You can do that with what i just told you, you can edit the pixels as you wish them to be and make it same as advanced browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good startingpoint. It doesn't work so well in the demo, but there are solutions in the final comments and the code looks fairly easy to improve upon: http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2008/05/Viewing-Option-Text-in-IE7-thats-Wider-than-the-Select-List.cfm