# Web dropdownlist: when select item, the select area don`t grow. only IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, select, drop-down-menu

I got a select, in which the select area don't grow automathicatly. In chorme, and firefox does.

How can I fix it?

IE case:
[image: IE case:]

Chrome case:
[image: Chrome case]

Comment: Can you post the select source code as an example? Also, if you have this live on a site, that too would help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article [here](http://css-tricks.com/1994-select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/). It's a problem with IE and you basically have to fix it with javascript.

For a similar question with answer (and code) check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie) StackOverflow post.

And for good measure... [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/selectfix) is a jQuery plugin meant to solve just this issue in IE 6/7/8.

Comment: It's the same sort of issue between the browsers, so it should world for all of them. I updated my post and added some other resources.

Comment: Sorry but, don't work, the width: auto is not a solution for IE8. I fixed it using a double div component. Cheers