# IE select width issue again... but with short options and jsf

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, jsf

I resolved IE select width problem of not displaying long values in dropdown menu like it was suggested in this article: 
http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/fix-for-ie-select-dropdown-with-fixed.html

Unfortunately there is a problem with this solution when all your options are smaller then set by default width. In that situation this code:

```
drpLst.style.width = 'auto';
```

makes combo smaller on mouse down, and bigger on option click which make not nice "jumping effect"

I solved it with this code:

```
                         <script type='text/javascript'>
                           function SetWidthToAuto(drpLst, c) {            
                                 drpLst.style.width = 'auto';  

                                  if(drpLst.clientWidth &lt; c) {
                                      drpLst.style.width = c.toString(); 
                                   }
                                   else {
                                      drpLst.style.width = 'auto';  
                                   } 
                               }  
                           function ResetWidth(drpLst, c) {  
                               drpLst.style.width =c.toString(); 
                               }  
                         </script>
```

c parameter is width I want my comoBox to be.

Unfortunately it ends with another problem - after changing option, selected value is not being displayed  (and selected in fact). Problem is with fragment of code that solve "jumping effect":

```
drpLst.style.width = c.toString();
```

because after deleting it works fine.

I am using jsf and facelests on view site.

I will be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdownlist width in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

Comment: Please note that the concrete problem has essentially completely nothing to do with JSF. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using a different server side language to generate HTML/CSS/JS or even when you're hardcoding that HTML/CSS/JS in a plain vanilla `*.html` file. In future pure HTML/CSS/JS related questions, you'll reach a wider audience if you omit JSF from the picture.