# Reduce width of selectOneMenu jsf lists without truncating the Menu items

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2

I have a `selectOneMenu` on my JSF page. I want to rearrange various fields on the page and for that I used `style="width:150px;"` attribute to restrict the width of the `selectOneMenu` lists.

This does restrict the Size of list and UI is looking good, But when I click on the list to select an item the display items are also restricted to the width I set and thus are truncated.

Is there any way using which, I restrict the size of collapsed list but when I expand a `selectOneMenu`, I see complete menu items which are not truncated?

[image]

Comment: So.. You're using IE6/7/8? This question then duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie/ Note: not a JSF problem. Just plain HTML/CSS/JS problem. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML/CSS/JS code generator.

Comment: @BalusC : Yes the application is IE8 certified. I cant move it to other browser. Any suggestion(s) how it can be done assuming Environment is fixed?

Comment: Just click the duplicate question link?

Comment: @BalusC: Yup..Sorry.. Got the answer. Thanks (y)

Answer (score 0):

Use in the header of your xhtml and configure as you like the following css:

```
.ui-selectonemenu{width: 9.2% !important;}
.ui-selectonemenu-label{width: 100% !important;}
```