# Small dropdown, large data

Tags: html, css

I have limited space and element in a dropdown with a large amount of text.

It it possible to have the dropdown width small but the popup of the list large?

**Edit:** I'm using IE

Comment: @SrikanthAD Maybe I don't have the term correctly. When user click on a dropdown, a list of items appear. That's the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid IE is the cuplrit here. Other browsers give you whatever width you need for your `option`s and leave the select box at the size you define but IE8 and lower cuts it off to the width of the parent `select` box.

The answer lies with jQuery and is wonderfully documented here: [Dropdownlist width in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

Comment: Good catch, yes i'm using IE.

Comment: No problem, I assumed that was the issue having fixed something similar on a `select` I was working on recently having tested in IE.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. And in current browsers, you don’t have to do anything special for the different sizes to work. Just set the `width` of your `select`, and the `option`s will still be as big as they need to be.

```html
<select id="menu">
    <option>short</option>
    <option>a quite long option that is wider than the select</option>
    <option>another option</option>
</select>
```

```css
#menu {
    width: 100px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/x9kQj/)

This works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10:

[image: short select with long options popup in Firefox]

[image: short select with long options popup in Chrome]

[image: long options popup of select in IE10]

But IE9 doesn’t support this:

[image: short select with short options popup in IE9]

Comment: This makes complete sense but unfortunately IE is nonsensical and cuts it off at the width of the select box. Can't define the width of the `option`s either.

Comment: @ScottBrown Maybe I'm missing something here, but I didn't hear any mention of ie in the question.

Comment: @zazvorniki Fair enough but I'd have thought that the OP wanted this to work across all browsers. They wouldn't have encountered the issue using a Gecko or Webkit browser so presumed they'd encountered the IE issue I described in my comment and answer.

Comment: @ScottBrown You can actually have a drop down misbehave in webkit and gecko if you don't put a width on it. I've had the same thing happen before. :)

Comment: @zazvorniki I did loads of presuming and guessed the OP had defined a width as they said that they had limited space. But you're quite right, no browser is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can help you, but i found something on css-tricks :

http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/

Take a look, hope it could help you!