# Is it possible to add an horizontal scroll bar to an html select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have below html code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvoooooooooooooooootooooooolargeeeeeeeeeeee</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is when it goes beyond the page then it gives vertical scroll bar. But the problem is if the value is too large then select box width is auto expanded to accommodate the width of the value. But i don't want it to expand. **I want a horizontal scrollbar to come if the option value is too large**.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can't give it a horizontal scrollbar. You're only options are to either restrict its width with css, or restrict the amount of text in the options.

Comment: why would you want a horizontal scroll bar, that seems nasty. Just make your select wider using width in CSS.

Comment: @Kevin, is there any alternative?

Comment: @user755806 Yes, don't use a select.

Comment: @Liam, if the value is too large then everything cannot be accoommodated right?

Comment: Of course! The alternative will be to wrap you select box in a div with a specific width and overflow auto. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7918399/439427

Comment: If i take the div then it would become the list box which i dont want..

Comment: What you want isn't possible with standard HTML.

Comment: You might consider using jQuery for this. Its almost impossible without that.

Comment: okay..is there any jquery plugin that i can use to get horizontal scroll bar? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is not possible. However, there is no need for a scrollbar on the option list if your goal is simply to make the `select` small while keeping the options fully visible. If you limit the width of your `select` through CSS, you will see that the browser automatically makes the whole width of the option list visible.

```css
select { width: 100px; }
```

[image: option list is wider than the select]

**Edit:** See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18150649/578288) on this topic. Firefox, Chrome, and IE10 will make the option list wider than the `select` if necessary, but IE9 will not. The other answers to that question link to this question with fixes for old IE: [Dropdownlist width in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73960/578288).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The native controls are completely governed by the browsers HTML renderer. You'll need to look at a `<select>` styling plugin if you want to style the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant do horizontal scrollbars using the default select boxes. You could try using a javascript replacement like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Both of these allow you to format the dropdown options with CSS and you should be able to control their formatting however you like.