# add horizontal scroll to drop-down field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add horizontal scroll to drop-down field?

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tunwagr3)

My **select>option** text is too long, For this reason i want to end-user have scroll (horizontal scroll) in drop-down fields.

**CSS:**

```
#id1{
    width: 100px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715705/always-show-vertical-scrollbar-in-select

Comment: No! @Mohammad my option text is too long, because i have to add  horizontal scroll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add an horizontal scroll bar to an html select box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405484/is-it-possible-to-add-an-horizontal-scroll-bar-to-an-html-select-box)