# list box values gets truncated in gwt

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I am using gwt list box. While adding values in list box, if the length of value is more than length of list box, the text for value gets truncated.I am getting this issue in IE only. It works fine in Firefox and chrome. IT automatically expands in both the browsers.
Please suggest some workaround.
Attached is screenshot from Internet Explore.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

Comment: Thanks Anders. Above link helped me a lot. and it worked for me.